# Max 4 lines AND a total of 140 characters in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am using *shouldChangeTextIn* on the UITextView and I am able to limit the TextView to either a maximum of 4 lines OR a maximum of 140 characters using the following code in *shouldChangeTextIn*:

Max 4 lines:

```
    let existingLines = textView.text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    let newLines = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    let linesAfterChange = existingLines.count + newLines.count - 1

    return linesAfterChange <= textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines
```

Max 140 characters:

```
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

    return newText.utf16.count < 140
```

However, I want to combine these two so it checks for both and I am not able to figure it out. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Best regards,
Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the bool values instead of returning it and combine them with an `&&` and return it.

```
let existingLines = textView.text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
let newLines = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
let linesAfterChange = existingLines.count + newLines.count - 1
let linesCheck = linesAfterChange <= textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines

let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
let characterCountCheck = newText.utf16.count < 140

return linesCheck && characterCountCheck
```

**Sidenote:** Avoid using `NSString` in Swift. You can do the same thing with `String`.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if let textViewString = textView.text, let range = Range(range, in: textViewString) {
        let newString = textViewString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    }
    return condition
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried this, but it does not work as expected. For instance: If I write 139 characters, then use a new line - it is not possible to do any input at all. Not even backspace to remove previously entered text. The cursor is stuck in the position it is in.

Comment: @fisher when you are 139, you would have probably reached the 3 line limit?

Comment: Nope, I have not. And it is not possible to use the back key either. So something is not working properly. I’ll do some more testing!

Comment: @fisher can you share the rest of the class?

Comment: My bad, I was adjusting the maxLimit (140) dynamically - reducing the maxLimit by 10 for each newline entered. This is what lead to the freeze. I removed the dynamic adjustment and it now works as expected. Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Combine the boolean values with && (and operator) and return the result

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        let existingLines = textView.text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
        let newLines = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
        let linesAfterChange = existingLines.count + newLines.count - 1

        let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

        return linesAfterChange <= textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines && newText.utf16.count < 140
    }
```